# A version of co-Hopf property for groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I would like to know if there is a reasonably common name for the following variation of being co-Hopfian for groups:

A group G is called ? if G is not isomorphic to a subgroup of infinite index in G.

For example, finitely generated nilpotent groups and virtually polycyclic groups have this property. But does this property have a name?

Comment: I've never seen a terminology for this. Maybe I'd use "$\infty$-cohopfian". In module theory, there's a notion of "weakly cohopfian", namely a module in which every injective homomorphism has an essential image, but it sounds distinct.

Comment: Exercise: every subgroup of $\mathbf{Q}^d$ is $\infty$-cohopfian.

Comment: OK, thanks. By the way, solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups like BS(1,2) are also "∞-cohopfian", right?

Comment: Yes, and more generally minimax virtually solvable groups, which includes $BS(1,2)$ and more generally all finitely generated virtually solvable subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Q})$. Indeed these groups have a notion of "length" which is the number of factors that are $\mathbf{Z}$ or a $p$-Prüfer $C_{p^\infty}$ in a subnormal series all of whose factors are cyclic, $p$-Prüfer or finite, and passing to an infinite index subgroup strictly decreases the length. The length of $BS(1,2)$, in this sense, is 3. Actually, in $BS(1,2)$, all infinite index subgroups are virtually abelian.

Comment: Other examples of ?-groups are fundamental groups of closed surfaces. By the way, finetly generated nonabelian free groups have the opposite property: they are not co-hopfian but cannot be isomorphic to their finite-index subgroups.

Comment: Yes, thanks, Anton. However, for this opposite property I have actually seen a term in the literature: "finitely co-Hopfian". https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1785.pdf

Comment: Then perhaps, your property may be called  *infinitely co-Hopfian* (or $\infty$-cohopfian as Yves suggested).

Comment: I've thought quite hard about this property, and haven't seen a name. Infinitely co-Hopfian sounds good. While we're collecting examples, the surface example can be vastly generalised: I believe Strebel proved that infinite-index subgroups of PD_n groups have cd less than n.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Of course, (hyperbolic) closed surface groups are co-Hopfian, and so they are infinitely co-Hopfian for that reason. But it's a different story with f.g. abelian groups, BS(1,2) and f.g. nilpotent groups (many of which are not co-Hopfian). For me a part of the motivation here is thinking about the corresponding geometric property: a metric space X is coarsely co-Hopfian if every coarse embedding from X to X is  coarsely onto (and hence is a coarse equivalence, and, in the case of X being a geodesic metric space, a quasi-isometry).